# CSS selector first position after not selector

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="body-page-check-in-list">
    ...
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">
    ...
</div>
```

Now I want to add css for first class `body-page-check-in-item` without class `checked`. I have tried doing this:

```
.body-page-check-in-item:not(.checked) {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But that will apply the css to the entire class `body-page-check-in-item` without class `checked` instead of just the first class.

I tried googling and changing like adding `:first-child`, `:first-of-type` after `not` but that gives error **Rule doesn't have all its properties in alphabetical order.**.

So, how do I apply css to the first class that doesn't have `checked`?

Your answer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```css
.body-page-check-in-item.checked + :not(.checked) {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-page-check-in-list">
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">a</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">b</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">c</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">d</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case class `checked` is separated by some `div` that don't have `checked` class like: `<div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">b</div> <div class="body- page-check-in-item">c</div> <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">d</div> <div class="body-page-check-in-item">e</div>` I just want `<div class="body-page-check-in-item">e</div>` (or the next class immediately after the last class have `checked` class) apply CSS, what do I do? I only want it to apply to the `div` near the last `div` that has the class `checked` instead of the whole.

Comment: @TầnQuảng I would recommend asking another question.

Comment: I asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415996/css-selector-add-css-to-next-position-after-last-match-case-of-not-selector/
Can you go take a look at it?