# CSS selector add css to next position after last match case of :not selector

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="body-page-check-in-list">
    ...
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">a</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">b</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">c</div>            <!-- c (1) -->
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">d</div>            <!-- d (2) -->
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">e</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">f</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">g</div>            <!-- g (3) -->
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">h</div>            <!-- h (4) -->
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">i</div>            <!-- i (5) -->
    ...
</div>
```

Now I want to add css for class `body-page-check-in-item` without class `checked` of last match of `:not` selector. I have tried doing this:

```
.body-page-check-in-item:not(.checked) {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But that will match all `c (1)`, `d (2)`, `g (3)`, `h (4)`, `i (5)`. I asked about this before, one solution is to change to:

```
.body-page-check-in-item.checked + :not(.checked) {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

But that solution will match both `d (2)` and `g (3)` and is iterable after that.

However, I need a selector that apply the css only once, for the next `div` after the last `div` that has the class `checked` (i.e. in the example it will only apply css to class at position `g (3)` and class at position `d (2)` will not be apply CSS.

What should I change to?

Your answer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to target `d (2)` and `i (5)`?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Are not.  I need a selector that apply the css only once, for the next `div` after the last `div` that has the class `checked` (i.e. in the example it will only apply css to class at position `g (3)` and class at position `d (2)` will not be apply CSS.

Comment: Are you able to show styles you want to apply to the element with that selector? In your example you want to add styles to g(3), right?

Comment: but selector `.body-page-check-in-item.checked + :not(.checked)` does it well - https://i.ibb.co/TYRnh6f/image.png

Comment: @s.kuznetsov but he wants to ignore (c) in case there are `.checked` after it

Comment: That's not possible with CSS alone, you'd have to use javascript to do that.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov As you can see from the picture you sent, `c` and `g` will both have css applied. However, I only want `g` to have css applied and `c` to NOT have css applied.

Comment: @TầnQuảng, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognise that you'll probably want to achieve this entirely without javascript, but one approach would be to use javascript to:

- identify your target-element
- add a class to that target-element

and *then* you can use that class for styling in your CSS.

For the example you've given, you could deploy the following javascript:~

```
// GET ALL ITEMS
const allItems = [... document.querySelector('.body-page-check-in-item')];

// GET CHECKED ITEMS
const checkedItems = [... document.querySelector('.body-page-check-in-item.checked')];

// GET LAST CHECKED ITEM
const lastCheckedItem = checkedItems[(checkedItems.length - 1)];

// GET INDEX OF LAST CHECKED ITEM
const indexOfLastCheckedItem = allItems.indexOf(lastCheckedItem);

// GET TARGET ITEM
const targetItem = document.querySelector('.body-page-check-in-item')[(indexOfLastCheckedItem + 1)];

// APPLY TARGET CLASS TO TARGET ITEM
targetItem.classList.add('my-target-item');
```

And *now* you can style `.my-target-item` in your CSS:

```
.my-target-item {
  [... STYLES HERE...]
}
```

Comment: Can you convert it to jQuery?

Comment: @Tần Quảng - Yes, I can. And if you really, really (really, really) want me to, I will. But my recommendation (_very_ strong recommendation) is that you keep using javascript until you are comfortable with it because all the excellent reasons why jQuery became popular in 2006-07 (mostly cross-browser compatibility, but also a couple of clever methods which didn't exist in JS at the time) were taken note of by the architects of javascript some time ago. jQuery did javascript a huge favour and helped to push it in a progressive, positive direction. The 2007 jQuery of today ***is*** javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a life hack to dynamically target the last selector `.body-page-check-in-item.checked`, but I couldn't do that. If this html structure is constant (unchanged), then this will be the actual solution, using the pseudo-class `:nth-last-child()`, specifying the *number* of this selector.

```css
.body-page-check-in-item.checked:nth-last-child(4) + :not(.checked) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-page-check-in-list">
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">a</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">b</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">c</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">d</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">e</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item checked">f</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">g</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">h</div>
    <div class="body-page-check-in-item">i</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been thinking a lot over the past few days. I probably wouldn't be able to do it without using Javascript.